# What's the meaning of: "what does X mean for Y?"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> What does the sober scientific view mean for man’s self-image?

It seems that the meaning of the sentence above depends on understanding the structure below:

> "what does X mean for Y?

Could you please tell me what it means? And how can I rewrite it?

The fuller text is here:

> Nietzsche was keenly interested in this new view of life. ‘All we
>   need,’ he later wrote, ‘is a chemistry of moral, religious, aesthetic
>   ideas and feelings, a chemistry of all those impulses that we
>   ourselves experience in the great and small interactions of culture
>   and society, indeed even in solitude.’ In the last third of the
>   nineteenth century, numerous scientists and philosophers were hard at
>   work on this ‘chemistry,’ a biological theory of existence without
>   God. But the questions on Nietzsche’s mind were altogether different:
>   **What does the sober scientific view mean for man’s self-image?** Does it render man larger or smaller? Does man stand to lose everything,
>   or is something to be gained from seeing things more clearly? These
>   questions formed the backdrop for his transcendent essay ‘On Truth and
>   Fals

ehood.’

Comment: In *What does X mean **for** Y?*, that particular choice of preposition is strongly associated with contexts where ***Y*** is something "abstract" - or at least, incapable of ***understanding** [what X "means"). What we're asking is *How does X **affect** Y?* On the other hand, we usually say *What does X mean **to** Y?* where ***Y*** is a person (or group of people) where what we're asking is *What does X **think** Y means?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"If (the biological theory of existence without God) is correct, what are the implications for humanity's view of itself?"